# View Component Tag Helper Not Recognised In .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to use View Components using tag helpers in a Razor page in a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 project.

Invoking as follows works:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("LeftSidebar")
```

Using the tag helper however doesn't and what's more Visual Studio does not seem to recognise the "vc" tag at all:

```
<vc:left-sidebar></vc:left-sidebar>
```

I have added the "addTagHelpers" to the _ViewImports.html file but it's not picking it up. I also read somewhere it requires a model so tried doing that with no joy.

Anyone else had this? Literally have wasted hours and will go back to the non-tag helper syntax for now.

Answer (score 3):

My mistake was including a ";" at the end of the add tag helper in the _ViewImports file.
Fixing this, cleaning the project and rebuilding everything sprung to life.

Comment: Found out mine was adding a comment on the same line as the addTagHelper because I wanted to keep some notes.